# Find count of rows in first table that match ids of row of second table with max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

Table 1:

- id

Table 2:

- id
- date

I need to find the count of rows of the t1 such that, for all rows with id of t1 that match ids of t2, select row with max date of t2.

Final Count should include only rows that satisfy max date of t2 > 30 days from present date.

Queries tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
ON t2.id = (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE id = t1.id ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1);

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.id=t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.date;
```

Note: The queries that I tried are no where near what the final query would look like, that I'm aware. I tried breaking the problem into intermediate parts, such as tried fetching all the rows of t1 with matched ids of t2, then I tried fetching only the latest one etc.

I'm having trouble thinking in terms of fetching rows from 1st table, but conditionally matching ids to the 2nd table. Im not being able to think in terms of SQL.

Comment: what is your date column type?

Comment: Its a sql date type.

Comment: What have you tried? You are more likely to get help if you show that you cannot do something rather than just asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, posting the stuff I have tried.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `DATE_ADD()` function to add days to your current date which get it by `NOW()` function:

```
select count(table1.id), max(table2.date) from table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
group by table2.date
having DATE(table2.date) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select      Count(T1.id)
From        Table1 T1
            inner join
            Table2 T2
            On T1.id = T2.id
where       T2.Date = ( Select  Max(Date)
                        from    Table2
                        where   Date > DATEADD(dd,30,cast(getdate() as date)))
```