# Get count(table1_id) based on max(table2_date) that is equal to given date. But each table1_id has many table2_dates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following data

Table 1: customers

```
|---|-----|
|id |name |
|---|-----|
|1  |Bob  |
|---|-----|
|2  |Alice|
|---|-----|
```

Table 2: subscriptions

```
|---|------------|-------------|
|id |customer_id |end_date     |
|---|------------|-------------|
|1  |1           |2020-03-16   |
|---|------------|-------------|
|2  |1           |2020-04-05   |
|---|------------|-------------|
|3  |2           |2020-02-05   |
|---|------------|-------------|
|4  |1           |2020-05-04   |
|---|------------|-------------|
|5  |2           |2020-03-16   |
|---|------------|-------------|
```

I need the count of customers where max(subscriptions.end_date) of each customer is equal to today.

My current query

```sql
select COUNT(customers.id), MAX(customer_payments.package_end_date) 
from `customers` 
inner join `customer_payments` on `customer_payments`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` 
group by `customer_payments`.`package_end_date` 
having DATE(customer_payments.package_end_date) = '2020-03-16'
```

It is returning the customers who have end_date as today also; but not of the greatest date. In the given data, if I run the query for today's date, I am getting the count 2. It is selecting both customer_id 1 and 2 even though the customer_id of 1 has the greatest date than today.

I have also tried queries mentioned in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651063/find-count-of-rows-in-first-table-that-match-ids-of-row-of-second-table-with-max) also getting the same output.

Comment: paste your sql...

Comment: Sorry for that, edited the question with the SQL in running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(id) as counted, id from subscriptions where customer_id in (select customer_id as avail_customers from subscriptions where end_date = '2020-03-16' group by customer_id) group by customer_id
```